# How can I test if a setTimeout was called appropriately?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, settimeout, sinon

```
function restartService(startTime) {
  const endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  const fiveMinLeft = 5 * 60 * 1000 - (endTime - startTime);
  console.log(startTime, endTime, fiveMinLeft);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('clock');
    Producer.create({
      queueUrl: process.env.MY_QUEUE
    }).send([{
      stuff: true
    }], (err) => {
      console.log('err', err);
    });
  }, fiveMinLeft);

  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

My test is

```
  it.only('send a message after 5 minutes to the queue', (done) => {
    const msg = 'msg'
    const sendStub = sinon.spy();
    const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();

    sinon.stub(global.db.Deposit, 'findAll').returns(Promise.resolve([{
      id: 2
    }]));

    sinon.stub(global.db.Transaction, 'findOrCreate').returns(Promise.resolve());
    sinon.stub(Producer, 'create').returns({
      send: sendStub
    });

    WatcherService.handleMessage(msg, () => {
      global.db.Transaction.findOrCreate.restore();
      global.db.Deposit.findAll.restore();
      Producer.create.should.be.called();

      done();
    });

    clock.tick(5 * 1000 * 60);
  });
```

This times out. I've increased the `timeout` of the test function, but it'll still ultimately timeout. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example ? You are showing test using `WatcherService.handleMessage` but code with `restartService`, so not easy to connect what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mocha I set the timeout as follows:

> ```
> it("send message", function(done) {
>     this.timeout(15000);
>     setTimeout(() => {
>            ...
>            done()
>      }, 5000);
>   })
> ```

Notice one thing: I am using "function" so that "this" is the correct object.

[From Site](https://mochajs.org/#test-level)